# Scroll down the page automatically until the user scrolls up

Tags: javascript

I got this simple script to scroll down the page

```
function scrollDown() {
     window.scrollBy(0,50); // horizontal and vertical scroll increments
}

scrolldelay = setTimeout('scrollDown()',100); // scrolls every 100 milliseconds
```

Now I wish to intercept when the user scrolls up himself to stop the setTimeout with a

```
clearTimeout(scrolldelay);
```

Any idea? **Preferable with pure js**

An alternative to accepted answer is here: http://jsfiddle.net/Vy8tW/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var start = (function() {
    function scrollTop() {
        return window.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop || (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop)
    }

    var top = scrollTop();
    var interval;
    window.onscroll = function() {
        var newtop = scrollTop();
        if (newtop < top) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
        top = newtop;
    };
    return function() {
        interval = setInterval(function() {
            window.scrollBy(0, 50);
        }, 100);
    }
}());

start();
```

How it works: Each time the page is scrolled, it compares the current scrollTop to the previous one. If we detect that the page has been scrolled up, we stop the interval.

You can re-start the scroll by calling start() again.

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/fR9Wt/3/

Comment: Perfect solution, altho I prefer simpler code in this case. I wrote this http://jsfiddle.net/Vy8tW/ with onmousewhell

Comment: Nice solution too. Won't work with the pageup/pagedown keys, however ;)

Comment: Yes of course, will work only with the whell, but this is not a problem

Comment: just in case I want to re-trigger the automatic scroll down after the clearInterval. I thought to append with a position:absolute a link that does a new setInterval... How would you do it?

Comment: I saw, nice solution, even tho i think it's better to `re-start();` only the `setInterval` part :) but it's fine anyway

Comment: Yes that's what it does. `start` is just the returned function at the end, it only calls setInterval().

Answer (score 1):

You need to capture the scroll event from the user.

If you're using jquery (or perhaps a similar library that offers similar functionality) you can detect it with .scroll()

```
$('#target').scroll(function() {
    clearInterval(scrolldelay);
});
```

Otherwise, you'll need to capture the scroll event yourself. If this intended for cross-browser use, the event naming scheme will be "scroll" for standard browsers, and "onscroll" for IE.

This page has some very basic examples, http://help.dottoro.com/ljurkcpe.php

Comment: i only need for chrome. I think i can use onmousewheel to be safe that my scrollDown functions doesn't get triggered

Comment: window.scrollBy() triggers a scroll event ;-)