# make a page scroll down to its very end, every 5 seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Update:

Sorry about the confusion.

What I'm trying to do is making a web page **scroll down** to its very end, every 5 seconds, how can I do that?

I tried repeat pressing the `end` key to get this happen, but I fails.

**These were my attempts:**

```
function pressEnd() {
    $('body').keypress({keyCode: 35});
}

setInterval(function () {
    pressEnd();
}, 5000);
```

And:

```
$('body').trigger('keydown', {which: 35});
```

And:

```
var event = $.Event('keydown', {keyCode: 35});
$('body').trigger(event);
```

---

Also tried to change the selector from `body` to `document` and `window`!

What am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to simulate key press events programatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/is-it-possible-to-simulate-key-press-events-programatically)

Comment: Are you trying to auto scroll with time interval?
Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13813257/autoscroll-with-setinterval-clearinterval

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7318272/3898339  is the solution, you are  looking for. modify interval time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

This script will auto scroll down to the bottom of page every 5 sec with animation duration of 500 ms

```
function scrollDown(el) {
    el.animate({
        scrollTop: el[0].scrollHeight
    }, 500, function() {
        scrollUp(el)
    });
};


 $(document).ready(function() { 
window.setInterval(function(){
  scrollDown($("html,body"));
}, 5000);
})
```

SEE fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/BDc6S/240/

**Previously**

Create a function to send `end key` and call it every 5 sec using jQuery `window.setInterval(function(){})`on  `$(document).ready(function() {})` like

```
function myFunction() {
var key35 = $.Event("keydown", { keyCode: 35 });
$("body").trigger(key35);
alert("end key pressed");
}

$(document).ready(function() { 
window.setInterval(function(){
  myFunction();
}, 5000);
})
```

SEE FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/utp2sfm4/

Comment: Sorry guys, I wasn't clear enough in my question!. I don't want to click the `end` key for the sake of clicking it, I wanted to click it to do a scroll down by this. I'm so sorry, I updated the question!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the code in the jQuery ready function like below.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
        $('body').keydown(function(event) {
            var keyCode =  event.which;
        alert("You pressed the key code: " +  keyCode );
    });
});
```

Here is a JSFiddle with the working example.
https://jsfiddle.net/txnL8699/

Comment: Sorry guys, I wasn't clear enough in my question!. I don't want to click the `end` key for the sake of clicking it, I wanted to click it to do a scroll down by this. I'm so sorry, I updated the question!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var event = $.Event('keydown', {keyCode: 35});

setInterval(function () {
  $('body').trigger(event);
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Sorry guys, I wasn't clear enough in my question!. I don't want to click the `end` key for the sake of clicking it, I wanted to click it to do a scroll down by this. I'm so sorry, I updated the question!

Answer (score 0):

its working fine when put your code inside the ready function.its triggering properly

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
setInterval(function () {
    pressEnd();
}, 5000);
});
function pressEnd(){
// Create a new jQuery.Event object with specified event properties.
var e = jQuery.Event("keydown", { keyCode: 35 });
// trigger an artificial keydown event with keyCode 64
jQuery("body").trigger( e );
}
```

Comment: Sorry guys, I wasn't clear enough in my question!. I don't want to click the end key for the sake of clicking it, I wanted to click it to do a scroll down by this. I'm so sorry, I updated the question!